# Converting numbers into timestamps (inserting colons at specific places)

Tags: autohotkey

I'm using AutoHotkey for this as the code is the most understandable to me. So I have a document with numbers and text, for example like this

`120344` text text text

`234000` text text

and the desired output is

`12:03:44` text text text

`23:40:00` text text

I'm sure StrReplace can be used to insert the colons in, but I'm not sure how to specify the position of the colons or ask AHK to 'find' specific strings of 6 digit numbers. Before, I would have highlighted the text I want to apply StrReplace to and then press a hotkey, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this that doesn't need my interaction. Even just pointing to the relevant functions I would need to look into to do this would be helpful! Thanks so much, I'm still very new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hfontanez's answer was very helpful in figuring out that for this problem, I had to use a loop and substring function. I'm sure there are much less messy ways to write this code, but this is the final version of what worked for my purposes:

```
Loop, read, C:\[location of input file]
{
  { If A_LoopReadLine = ;
   Continue ; this part is to ignore the blank lines in the file
  }
  { 
    one := A_LoopReadLine
    x := SubStr(one, 1, 2)
    y := SubStr(one, 3, 2)
    z := SubStr(one, 5)
    two := x . ":" . y . ":" . z
    FileAppend, %two%`r`n, C:\[location of output file]
   }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "timestamp" component is always 6 characters long and always at the beginning of the string, this solution should work just fine.

```
    String test = "012345 test test test";
    test = test.substring(0, 2) + ":" + test.substring(2, 4) + ":" + test.substring(4, test.length());
```

This outputs `01:23:45 test test test`

Why? Because you are temporarily creating a `String` object that it's two characters long and then you insert the colon before taking the next pair. Lastly, you append the rest of the `String` and assign it to whichever `String` variable you want. Remember, the `substring` method doesn't modify the `String` object you are calling the method on. This method returns a "new" `String` object. Therefore, the variable `test` is unmodified until the assignment operation kicks in at the end.

Alternatively, you can use a `StringBuilder` and append each component like this:

```
StringBuilder sbuff = new StringBuilder();
sbuff.append(test.substring(0,2));
sbuff.append(":");
sbuff.append(test.substring(2,4));
sbuff.append(":");
sbuff.append(test.substring(4,test.length()));
test = sbuff.toString();
```

You could also use a "fancy" loop to do this, but I think for something this simple, looping is just overkill. Oh, I almost forgot, this should work with both of your test strings because after the last colon insert, the code takes the substring from index position 4 all the way to the end of the string indiscriminately.